# Adding needed Software Sites to target platform definition

Tags: eclipse, p2, target-platform

I'm trying to deploy a target platform definition using an eclipse extension point but the problem is the same when distributing it as a ".target" file

I've an eclipse plugin with a "org.eclipse.pde.core.targets" extension referencing a target definition based on IU's (installable units) but it seems there is no way to deploy the needed "Available Software Sites" with it.

It seems that the "Available Software Sites" for target platforms are specific for each workspace. This means that my plugin's users, for each workspace, must define the "Available Software Sites" previously to add a target platform based on my template

It could be a way to do this without forcing them to do this work?

Comment: Posted in the eclipse forums (perhaps better explained): https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1035599/

Comment: Well, unlike in forums, you can edit posts in stackoverflow. Please also provide the "better explanation" here. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.